# Sum area of features intersecting atlas feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, intersection, expression, atlas, aggregation

I have AOI layer named "Clusters" which is set as the Atlas coverage layer for my project

I want to sum the area(Hectares) of specific intersecting features from my "Senwes_All_Fields_Alb_AND_IntStreek" layer in a text box in the print composer.

The "Senwes_All_Fields_Alb_AND_IntStreek" layer contains:
[image]

I would like to calculate the area of CATNAME_1 values intersecting the atlas feature using an expression

For example:

- Horticulture = 500 Hectares
- Non-pivot irrigated Annual Crop Cultivation / Planted Pastures = 2000 Hectares
- Old Fields = 1000 Hectares
- etc.

I have tried the aggregate function below, and got the TOTAL area of all CATNAME_1 values (Output preview: 347178.45651800046).

[image]

Now I would like to further break it down into the different values of CATNAME_1 as per example above.

How might I achieve that?

```
aggregate(
layer:= 'Senwes_All_Fields_Alb_AND_IntStreek',
aggregate:='sum',
expression:="AREA_HA",
filter:=intersects( $geometry,geometry(@atlas_feature) )
)
```